# Why NoSuchMethodError Exception is thrown if API-jar has this method and implementation

Tags: android

```
File f = new File(fullPath);            
long freeSpace = f.getFreeSpace();
```

I am using above snippet in android app. 
My app compiles fine, with sdk-15 jar.

The android phone where I run the app is Froyo

I get following error at runtime

```
      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.File.getFreeSpace
```

I looked up the docs for getFreeSpace() and it says since API-9. 
As I understand froyo is compliant with API-8 (and above, I guess ?) 
so I sort of know (but do not quite understand) that I can not call this function on platform froyo, but I can call it on platforms above API-8

**So my Question / Ambiguity is this**

Given the application compiles perfectly fine, I would assume that function f.getFreeSpace() and its implementation is available in the jar of API-15 which I am using.
Why would android throw a runtime exception when my app is compiled with jar file of API-15 and it should have the implementation of getFreeSpace() in the jar ? Why would the platform Froyo - API-8 be causing a problem if implementation is there in the API-15 jar. ?

Comment: stuff in api15 are not always in api8, that's why

Comment: and how do you expect froyo would know about an api 15 ?

Comment: You more or less answered your own question.  `getFreeSpace` was introduced in API-9, and you're getting an error on API-8, which is older than that.  The fact that you compiled it in API-15 is irrelevant, since the API level at runtime is whatever is available on the system.

Comment: @IanMcLaird The fact that you compiled it in API-15 is irrelevant - Can you please provide a reference for this in the docs somewhere or some article on it ?

Comment: @CommonsWare's answer sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would assume that function f.getFreeSpace() and its implementation is available in the jar of API-15 which I am using

"the jar of API-15" is not what you think it is.

At compile time, the JAR that you compile against is *not* part of the APK. It is a series of stub classes and methods, sufficient to allow the compilation to proceed. The real implementation of those classes and methods is in the firmware of the device.

> Why would android throw a runtime exception when my app is compiled with jar file of API-15 and it should have the implementation of getFreeSpace() in the jar ?

You have `getFreeSpace()` at compile time, using the compile-tile JAR. You will not have `getFreeSpace()` at runtime on an API Level 8 device, because that method does not exist in that version of Android.

> Why would the platform Froyo - API-8 be causing a problem if implementation is there in the API-15 jar. ?

Because what you think is the "API-15 jar" is only used at compile time, not at runtime.

There used to be more material on this on the Android Developers site, but it appears to have been lost as a part of the redesign from earlier in 2012.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, So if these api-sdk jars are mere hollow stubs for compile only, is it correct to assume that it does not make any difference at all as to which api-jar I link to ? just get the latest one and link it (being superset of functions) ? - As long as I am  not calling functions unsupported for my target plaform(s)

Comment: @Ahmed: "is it correct to assume that it does not make any difference at all as to which api-jar I link to ?" -- you need to compile against the API level that contains all classes and methods that you intend to call directly at runtime. "As long as I am not calling functions unsupported for my target plaform(s)" -- correct. You can use `android.os.Build` to find out the version of the device you are running on, so you can conditionally call newer methods on devices where it is safe.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, this was helpful and cleared a critical misconception from my mind. before posting I tried to look up android docs but was not able to find clear related info, Your answer sufficiently answers my question However I would like to have a detailed understanding on this subject so if you could share any article/refernce material I would highly appreciate it. Thanks once again